# Upgrade 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 composer fails

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.1

I'm working with a composer 2.4.0 and try to install 2.4.1

According [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

- [x] Determine whether your current catalog search engine is supported
- [x] Complete the Update and upgrade checklist
- [x] Set the pub/ directory root
- [x] Check PHP and environment settings
- [x] Switch to maintenance mode  `bin/magento maintenance:enable`
- [X] Check the status of cron jobs
- [x] Install the Composer update plugin
- [x] composer update No errors
- [x] composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.1 --no-update
- [x] composer update No errors after reorder composer.json for issue with

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "aheadworks/module-customer-segmentation": "^1.1",
        "aheadworks/module-reward-points": "^1.7",
        "aheadworks/module-shop-by-brand": "^1.2",
        "amasty/module-special-promo-pro": "^2.8",
        "amasty/paction": "^1.1",
        "amasty/payrestriction": "^2.3",
        "amasty/pgrid": "^1.9",
        "amasty/preorder": "^1.4",
        "amasty/shippingtablerates": "^1.7",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.4.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.1",
        "swissup/cache-warmer": "^1.0",
        "swissup/gdpr": "^1.3",
        "swissup/module-marketplace": "^1.7",
        "swissup/pagespeed": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "aheadworks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://dist.aheadworks.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        },
        "swissupartifacts": {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "/home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/swissup/artifacts"
        },
        "swissuplabs": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://ci.swissuplabs.com/api/packages.json"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

- [x] Clean caches and redis `rm -Rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* generated/code/* && redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis-server.sock FLUSHALL`
- [X] bin/magento setup:upgrade
- ERROR

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi\Model\GetEntitiesInterface in /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#3 /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#4 /home/tiendas/web/t in /home/tiendas/web/tiendafetichista.ovh/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

Comment: Hello ! I'm having the same issue here, did you find any solution ? Thanks !

Comment: @magentodev did you try flushing the redis cache?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and deleting the Redis cache is what fixed it for me. I am using Docker so I just removed the Redis data volume and restarted it, but otherwise you can clear it with the `redis-cli flushall` from the command line of the Redis host.

If it is running locally:

```bash
redis-cli flushall
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Read post. `redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis-server.sock FLUSHALL` Not all use redis with port. ;-)